# Mongoose self referenced schema not creating ObjectId for all sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Schema in mongoose that have a self referenced field, like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CollectPointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  collectPoints: [ this ]
});
```

when a CollectPoint object is inserted:

```
{
  "name": "Level 1"
}
```

it's ok, the result is like expected:

```
{
  "_id": "58b36c83b7134680367b2547",
  "name": "Level 1",
  "collectPoints": []
}
```

But when I insert self referenced sub documents,

```
{
  "name": "Level 1",
  "collectPoints": [{
    "name": "Level 1.1"
  }]
}
```

It gives me this:

```
{
  "_id": "58b36c83b7134680367b2547",
  "name": "Level 1",
  "collectPoints": [{
    "name": "Level 1.1"
  }]
}
```

Where is the `_id` of the child `CollectPointSchema`? I need this `_id`.

Comment: I solve this problem with [this recursive function](https://gist.github.com/GSchutz/100358d4a614b563da29e72c5f8cd5e9).

Answer (score 1):

You should build a new object when declaring your embedded `CollectPoint` items :

```
var data = new CollectPoint({
    name: "Level 1",
    collectPoints: [
        new CollectPoint({
            name: "Level 1.1",
            collectPoints: []
        })
    ]
});
```

This way the `_id` and `collectPoints` will be created by the instanciation of `CollectPoint` otherwise, you are just creating a plain JSONObject.

To avoid those kind of issues, build a [validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for your array that will trigger an error if its items have wrong type :

```
var CollectPointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    collectPoints: {
        type: [this],
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                if (!Array.isArray(v)) return false
                for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                    if (!(v[i] instanceof CollectPoint)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            message: 'bad collect point format'
        }
    }
});
```

This way the following will trigger an error :

```
var data = new CollectPoint({
    name: "Level 1",
    collectPoints: [{
        name: "Level 1.1",
        collectPoints: []
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, your answer cleared basic concepts in Mongoose that I didn't note. But I think is strange that when I add `collectPoints: [ this ]` it should force that `new ..()`, or maybe this relation should be in the model.. (sorry, just divagating here)