# How to add an objectID to recursively embedded subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a variation on the question asked and solved by @Guilherme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475905/mongoose-self-referenced-schema-not-creating-objectid-for-all-sub-documents) but my recursive embedded documents are within another schema like this;

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CollectPointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  collectPoints: [ this ]
});

var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    label: {type: String},
    points: [CollectionPointSchema]
});

const Group = mongoose.model("Group", GroupSchema);
```

I'd like to modify the solution that Guilherme proposed [here](https://gist.github.com/GSchutz/100358d4a614b563da29e72c5f8cd5e9) but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that the child folders were not being populated with the name: field. I think because that field is not in the top level of the schema. So as a work-around I have added the name: field to the parent schema like this;

```
var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    label: {type: String},
    name: {type: String},
    points: [CollectionPointSchema]
});
```

and I also needed to change the order of Guilherme's solution from this;

```
var FolderModel = mongoose.model('folders', FolderSchema);

FolderSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    recursive_reference(FolderModel, this, "folders")
  }

  next();
});
```

to this;

```
FolderSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    recursive_reference(FolderModel, this, "folders")
  }

  next();
});

var FolderModel = mongoose.model('folders', FolderSchema);
```

The result is that I have an unused field at the parent level, but it works.